# Maven, Flexmojos and generate goal : choose for destination another package than source

Tags: maven, flexmojos

I would like to know if there is a way to generate with `Flexmojos` and its `generate` goal another package than the source ? For example, if I have a Java class `foo.bar.A.java`, I would like to generatefor example `bar.foo.A.as` not `foo.bar.A.as`.

My problem is that I use :

```
<baseOutputDirectory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}/com/sim/gas3/base</baseOutputDirectory>
<outputDirectory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}/com/sim/gas3/</outputDirectory>
```

So a generated class must have package like `com.sim.gas3.foo.bar` whereas this plugin generates classes under `com/sim/gas3` with package `foo.bar` only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, just find it :

```
<translators>
    <translator>the.older.package=the.new.package</translator>
</translators>
```